# How to tell if various non US patents are granted vs applications?

Tags: granted

Regarding "World Patent application". I understand that the very basic basic process is:

1. Apply for a world patent application it stands in for an application in all the various countries that the inventor wants protection in.
2. Decide what countries the inventor wants protection in and apply in those countries.
3. Patents in various countries are either granted or not.

How does one tell if the individual patents applied for in each country has been granted or is pending/in some other state?

Specific countries I am interested in are: US, EP, CA, ES, AT, PT, BRP, SI, DK, DE

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the "kind codes"  that state with "A" are applications and those with a "B" are granted. That is a simplification and doesn't help you determine if the patent is expired or invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Every patent / patent application is followed by a kind code (E.g. A, B, U) which denotes the status of patent / patent application whether it is granted or under examination process. The status can be checked using national patent office database of all countries or in WIPO IP Portal.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:- A person can find out using national patent office patent depository for said application.

Long answer:- its a analysis based answer and limited to data indexed in web resource database.

> Decide what countries the inventor wants protection in and apply in
>   those countries.

1. WIPO applications are indexed in PATENTSCOPE database and it has a landing page for all applications. In bibliographic page there is a tab called 'National Phase' which lists all national phase entry details, now please note these details may be incorrect as some patent office may not report IB for national phase entry. but if online request of certified WIPO PCT application is made then these details will be updated here (no guarantees).

> Patents in various countries are either granted or not.
>   How does one tell if the individual patents applied
>   for in each country has been granted or is pending/in some other
>   state?

2. In general every patent has a country code followed by patent application or patent number followed by Kind code (e.g. A1, A2, B1 B2 etc) which can indicate status of the patent application. WIPO has provided [such list](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/standards/en/pdf/07-03-02.pdf)
3. Additionally a person has to check if national patent was granted that need to be done using Patent Register of subject country in case of any lapse, revocation, invalidation, surrender etc.

Comment: Thanks Pushpak. For some reason that procedure image is not loading for me???

Comment: What does this mean? " but if online request of certified WIPO PCT application is made then these details will be updated here (no guarantees)." Would that be an online request at the WIPO site?

Comment: I found the issue...our IT dept is blocking imgur.

Comment: When you file patent citing priority of national phase patent copy from WIPO is taken and WIPO mention such references

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer at all.

Comment: its ok i think I was under the impression that you know some bit about patents i have revised the answer in case you have any other issue leave a comment.

Comment: Perfect Pushpak. That document about what the various codes mean **really** helps a lot. Yes, I am a learning inventor.

Comment: Like i said even kind code can indicate patent is granted but it may be expired or lapsed which are not updated by kind codes. In all cases final status is dwelled inside respective patent office log file.